# Is there any powershell command to print a document without opening it?

Tags: powershell

I would like to use powershell command to print a pdf and word document

I tried using this one : `Get-Content -Path [path] | Out-Printer`

but this command opens the windows file explorer, the application (word or adobe depending on the file type) but doesn't print it

Is there any way to have a command print on background without opening anything ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually not but I use following trick by calling the right click "print" action.

```
Start-process -filepath "path to your file" -verb print
```

Filetype must support the "print" verb

It prints to the default printer, no choice

However programs open and are visible. Once done, office program are closed but adobe reader remains opened as process is still present. Asked from Adobe support it is by design as they decided to assume it is beneficial to maintain the process as could be used later. (no comment)